# rails send_file with pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Very simple...I just want to display a local pdf file that I have saved in my public directory inline and not as a link to download it.  So I guess I should be using send_file like so:

```
<%= send_file("http://localhost:3000/exex11.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline') %>
```

However, I get: `undefined method`send_file' for #<#:0x94c3020>` Note, that I know I should use root_url but I'm using localhost:3000 just for testing purposes.

And I checked that this works just to make sure that the file is there:

```
<%= link_to "The file", "http://localhost:3000/exex11.pdf" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I guess I should be using send_file like so

I suppose you should using that in your controller's action instead of using in view